# Robocopy - make a copy of single file in same directory

Tags: robocopy

Using robocopy is it possible to make a copy of a file in same directory?

Something like this...
robocopy c:\temp\file.txt c:\temp\file_copy.txt

Comment: Might I suggest that you ask this question at http://superuser.com/?  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: yep, sorry, this is actually going to be part of a windows script.  I just simplified it on here.  The above fails with error.  Incorrect syntax.

Comment: How about PowerShell?  Can I do the above with PS instead?

Comment: In Powershell
`Copy-Item c:\temp\file.txt c:\temp\file_copy.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**COPY** could be used. Use `/Y` to confirm an overwrite.

```
COPY /Y "C:\temp\file.txt" "C:\temp\file_copy.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was pulling my hair out to try and figure this problem out. I finally found my own solution and maybe it will help you too.

I noticed that the syntax used to select the entire directory could be used to select a single file.

```
ROBOCOPY "*" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

The above code will copy everything from the directory source folder to the directory output path.

Let's say you only wanted to copy 1 file from the directory source named "test.txt"

In order to do that use the following code:

```
ROBOCOPY "*test.txt" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

Thats about it. It works really well and will only copy the file name you want.

Alternatively you can use

```
ROBOCOPY "*.txt" "Directory source" "Directory Output unc path or non"
```

to copy out all text documents from the directory source.
Similarly this will also work with any .ext

.zip .exe .txt .pdf etc..

I signed up to answer this question with a better method. Let me know if I succeeded.